# Preserve texture and weight paint while subdividing

Tags: mesh, texturing, weight-painting, subdivision-surface

I am currently working with a low poly character that is rigged and I have already developed my game with it. Now I want to convert its mesh to a high poly one to get rid of hard edges during animation. I am trying to subdivide and apply smoothing in edit mode, but this is resulting into texture and weight paint getting destroyed. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You can duplicate your object, subdivide the second, bake the texture of the first onto the second one. The weight shouldn't be lost when you subdivide